# python pytest - receiving test parameters from outside

Tags: python, pytest

I am new to pytest framework and I wonder if there is a standard approach my pytests to receive parameters from other script. I guess the most common practice is to write `@pytest.fixture` that looks like:

```
@pytest.fixture
def param(request):
device = request.config.getoption("--parameter")
if parameter == 'A':
    return value_a
else:
    return default_value
```

And running my test with command `py.test --parameter=value_a`(this command is executed by some other script)

But if my test needs many parameters, lets say for example 10, that would be one long command. So I am asking what is the standard approach in situation like that - do I provide some kind of xml file or serialized dictionary with parameters and my fixture to take the parameters from them.

Also how my other script will know what kind of parameters to provide to my test - should there be test_parameters configuration file or some hardcoded data in my conftest.py, that holds the information for the parameters, or should I use get them by reading the signature of the tests with `from inspect import signature`.

**EDITED**

Here is a sample of my tests

```
class TestH5Client:
    # runs before everything else in the class
    def setup_class(cls, ip="11.111.111.111",
                    browserType="Chrome",
                    port="4444",
                    client_url="https://somelink.com/",
                    username="some_username",
                    hpassword="some_pass"):

        cls.driver = get_remote_webdriver(ip, port, browserType)
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(60)
        cls.client_url = client_url
        cls.username = username
        cls.password = password

    def teardown_class(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()

    def test_login_logout(self):
        # opening web_client
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
        self.driver.get(self.h5_client_url)

        # opening web_client log-in window
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.gettingStarted p:nth-child(4) a:nth-child(1)").click()

        # log in into the client
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(self.h5_username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(self.h5_password)
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()

        # clicking on the app_menu so the logout link appears
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(60)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("action-userMenu").click()

        # clicking on the logout link
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(60)
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#vui-actions-menu li:nth-child(3)").click()

        assert "Login" in self.driver.title

    def test_open_welcome_page(self):
        """fast selenium test for local testing"""
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
        self.driver.get(self.h5_client_url)
        assert "Welcome" in self.driver.title

    def test_selenium_fail(self):
        """quick test of selenium failure for local testing"""
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
        self.driver.get(self.h5_client_url)
        assert "NotInHere" in self.driver.title
```

I need all those parameters to be provided by an outside python providing test parameters framework. And I need to know how this framework should get the name of the parameters and how to run those tests with these parameters.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example of the issue you are facing

Comment: Are the parameters truly variable, or are they really just a set of configurations, like a dev server, qa server, prod server?

Comment: @Austin Hastings They are changed every week :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your answers in the comments, the data changes weekly.

So I'd suggest passing in a single parameter, the path to a file specifying the rest of your info.

Use whatever parsing mechanism you're already using elsewhere - XML, Json, whatever - or use something simple like a config file reader.

Create a fixture with session scope (like [this](http://pythontesting.net/framework/pytest/pytest-session-scoped-fixtures/#conftest)) and either give it some sensible defaults, or have it fail violently if it doesn't get a valid parameter file.